# Is there any way to get script file Globally?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages, global

I've 30 **.aspx** pages in my web application. And each page requires a same script file say **myscript.js**

I want to know is there any way to call this file globally for all the 30 pages? I don't want to use **MasterPage**.

Comment: Why you dont want to include this file on every page? Present browsers caching everything *.js files too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a base class, let all pages inherit from this base class, and have the base class add the script line to the page. Something like this:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected override OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    // add javascript to page here
  }
}

public class MyWebPage1 : BasePage
{
}

public class MyWebPage2 : BasePage
{
}

public class MyWebPage3 : BasePage
{
}
```